# How to define a second nginx location clause inside a puppet vhost?

Tags: nginx, puppet

I'm trying to setup a puppet configuration to define an nginx vhost that has multiple location clauses, one of which serves static content from a local directory and another that is a proxy to another local server. The documentation for the [nginx module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/jfryman/nginx) is very poor, so I'm having troubles understanding how to do this.

Here is basically the nginx configuration that I am *trying to achieve* (I created this manually):

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  myapp.example.com;

    location /admin/ {
        alias /path/to/my/app/;
        index index.html;
    }

    location / {
        # pass everything else to backend server
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

And here is the nginx config I have so far:

```
node 'web00' {
    class { 'nginx': }

    nginx::resource::vhost { 'myapp.example.com':
        www_root => '/path/to/my/app',
    }

    nginx::resource::upstream { 'backend_nodejs':
        members => [
            'localhost:9000',
        ],
    }
}
```

How do I add additional location clauses within the myapp.example.com vhost puppet config clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with nginx::resource::location definition:

```
node 'web00' {
    class { 'nginx': }

    nginx::resource::upstream { 'backend_nodejs':
        members => [
            'localhost:9000',
        ],
    }

    nginx::resource::vhost { 'myapp.example.com':
        proxy => 'http://backend_nodejs'
    }

    nginx::resource::location { '/admin':
      location => '/admin/',
      vhost => 'myapp.example.com',
      location_alias => '/path/to/my/app/'
      index_files => ['index.html']
    }    
}
```

Comment: This almost worked. I removed www_root in the vhost since that isn't allowed in combination with proxy. I also changed "index_files = [" to "index_files => [" (missing >).